# how to access webpage control in a class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I took a div id="DivErr" runat="server"

This is my Web Page written a class within

```
Public Class ReceiptInv Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Partial Class MyTimer
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared timer As New Timer(5000)

    ' Enable the timer to run
    Public Shared Sub StartRuning()
        AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timer_Elapsed
        timer.Start()
    End Sub

    ' This method will be called every 5 seconds
    Private Shared Sub timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        Dim TMR As New ReceiptInv

        TMR.DivErr.Visible = False
    End Sub
End Class
End Class
```

I want to make this DivErr visible false in every 5 seconds.
But error in line
TMR.DivErr.Visible = False

```
NullReferenceException Unhandled By Usercode
Object reference not set to an instance of an Object
```

Can anyone tell what i am doing wrong ?? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: make it visible false every 5 seconds...?? does this division shows up again after specific time period? can you elaborate on this

Comment: Try passing `div` control in `constructor` of `MyTimer`

Comment: Yes.. This Div is being shown time to time on every error and i want to make it visible false in every 5 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get a real instance of the page, then you can access the controls and properties of it. Since your method is `Shared` you cannot access controls of the current page's instance (easily).

But you can try to get the page-instance   via [HttpContext.CurrentHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.currenthandler.aspx).

```
Private Shared Sub timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    Dim page = TryCast(HttpContext.CurrentHandler, ReceiptInv)
    If page IsNot Nothing Then
        page.DivErr.Visible = False 
    End If
End Sub
```

However, why does the method need to be shared at all? A `Shared` timer is shared by all requests!

Apart from that i suspect that you're trying to make a control visible/invisible every 5th second. That won't work this way since you're using a server timer. You could use an `ASP.NET-Ajax-Timer` instead: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Error in line Dim page = TryCast(HttpContext.Current.Handler, ReceiptInv) Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Dev: when and from where do you call `StartRuning`? Note that i've edited my answer to use `CurrentHandler`.

Comment: @Dev: why is the timer shared at all?

Comment: Just because of some more additions in future. But i have removed Shared and put Public in place of it.

Comment: Now in Page_Load event i wrote.. Dim MYT As MyTimer
MYT.StartRuning(). Same error in this line..

Comment: @Dev: of course `MYT` is nothing after: `Dim MYT As MyTimer`, why don't you initialize it: `Dim MYT As New MyTimer`? Apart from that i suspect that you're trying to make a control visible/invisible every 5th second. That won't work this way since you're using a server timer. You could use an `ASP.NET`-Ajax- Timer instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404(v=vs.100).aspx